# Create a vertical list inside horizontally list html+css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a list that will look something like this:

--- Item   ---------------     Item2        ...etc (dashes are just for spacing on stackoverflow)

--subitem     ----------   -subitem2

--subitem     ----------   -subitem2

I know that i can create sub-lists using this syntax:

```
         <html>
          <ul> 
            <li>Item
                <ul> 
                   <li>subitem</li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li>Item2
                <ul> 
                   <li>subitem2</li>
                </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
          </html>
```

But how can i style them to meet my wish? I am usually pretty good at css but i have to admit that i do not use lists very often so i am a bit confused when it comes to styling them. Can you help me please?

Comment: is this what you looking for? http://jsbin.com/ocimu

Comment: Just make 2 columns..

Comment: @JoshC first..i need more than 2 columns...and second i can not use tables...

Comment: @SpiderLinked I'm not talking about HTML table columns, to clarify, see **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)**

Comment: if you think you can use always upvote and before asking questions, do a search and you will find the solution

Comment: @San...i tried your option..but it does not work...the sub elements are displayed horizontally.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to display tabular data. In that case just use a table.

Comment: Solved... using San's idea and a bit of rewriting from me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
}
ul ul{
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul ul li{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nXW56/12/